# HTML Nodes missing with HTMLAgilityPack from HtmlWeb

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack 1.11.28 on Visual Studio in VB.NET.  I'm trying to navigate a HTML table that is a little short on ids, so I'm navigating through nested tables manually. I'm stuck in a situation where a node clearly shows up in the InnerHtml for the parent table, but once I start entering child nodes it disappears. This missing node is also clearly visible in Firefox Inspector.

In this example I'm crawling through the page https://www.bricklink.com/catalogReqList.asp?nID=&viewDate=Y&viewType=E&viewStatus=A&viewAction=M&q=973c09

I start by grabbing the closest named element - id-main-legacy-table - into changeTableOuter:

```
Public Function GetBLMergedToItem(itemNum As String) As String
    Dim changeLogUrl = $"https://www.bricklink.com/catalogReqList.asp?nID=&viewDate=Y&viewType=E&viewStatus=A&viewAction=M&q={itemNum}"
    Dim changeHtml = New HtmlWeb().Load(changeLogUrl)
    Dim changeTableOuter = changeHtml.GetElementbyId("id-main-legacy-table")
```

When I look through the InnerHtml of changeHtml I can find this (consolidated for readability):

```
            ↓<table id="id-main-legacy-table" class="tb-main-content" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="779">
                ↓<tr bgcolor="#306fa3">
                    ↓<td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="min-height: 100px;" align="left" >
                        <!-- mError:  -->
                        <!-- Classic Contents Start -->
                        →<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="10" CELLSPACING="5" WIDTH="100%" BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">
                        →<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="10" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%" BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">
                        →<SCRIPT>
                        <!-- Classic Contents End-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Firefox shows the same thing: [image]

There are two tables in the  tag.  However when I ask to look at changeTableOuter, only one table appears as a child, not two:
[image]

This bears out in the InnerHtml which closes all the tags to the outertable immediately after the first subtable.

> 

I find it strange that the app is clearly pulling the full html but when I jumped to the containing table using GetElementbyId it loses data. Am I doing something wrong?

Let me know if including additional html here would be helpful.